# MS Access - What is the use of "!" , exclamation symbol

Tags: ms-access, vba, operators, ms-access-2007

I am new to MS Acces and would like to know what does the symbo "!" mean. 
For e.g.

1) What does "Tbl!Field" means and how does it differ from "Field" where "Tbl" is a atable name and "Field" is a column name.

I have some code that uses both the formats but not sure how do the two code differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recordsets, Tbl!Field would be the recordset (not table) name & the field name. You can also do Tbl("Field").

One advantage of Tbl("Field") is that you can use a variable name, like: Tbl(var1).

You may also see Tbl.Field, but I consider the period to be a property or method and shouldn't be used for fields.

Comment: Tom does it mean that whene ever we use Tbl!Field we need to use loop. What would result if we do not have a loop when using the format Tbl!Field.

Comment: Tbl!Field accesses the value of a field within ONE record. If you want to access multiple records, then you'll have to loop through them.